# Merging two hashmaps with their values combined as object of specific class

Tags: java, hashmap, collectors

I have a class like

```
public class Values {

    BigDecimal a;
    BigDecimal b;
}
```

And two maps with the same keys like

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = Map.of("A", 123.1, "B", 345.2, "C", 678.3);

Map<String, Double> map2 = Map.of("A", 543.5, "B", 432.2, "C", 654.3);
```

I want to merge those maps into one `Map<String, Values>` converting `Doubles` to `BigDecimals` on the way How can I achieve that? And maybe it's even possible without explicitly creating third map?

Example of desired output (`Doubles` are now `BigDecimals` as fields a and b of Values class)

```
Map<String, Values> map3
"A", {123.1, 543.5}
"B", {345.2, 345.2}
"C", {678.3, 654.3}
```

Tried solutions from close topics with stream and collectors and i guess i just cant figure it out.

Comment: You definitely need a third map as none of the input maps are a `Map<String, Values>`.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: Using static initializers for maps is considered bad form. I changed it to use `Map.of` which was introduced in Java 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over one of the input `Map`s:

```
    private static Map<String, Values> mergeMaps(Map<String, Double> map1Map<String, Double> map2) {
        Map<String, Values> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Double> e1:map1.entrySet()) {
            BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(e1.getValue());
            BigDecimal b = BigDecimal.valueOf(map2.get(e1.getKey()));
            result.put(e1.getKey(), new Values(a, b));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This makes use of a AllArgsConstructor of `Values` which can be easily done if you make use of java's `record`:

```
public record Values (BigDecimal a, BigDecimal b){}
```

Please note that this code assumes that both input maps have the same set of keys.

Answer (score 1):

As [@f1sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143736/1552534) suggested, just use one map and use its key to get the other value from the second map.  Here is a stream approach.

```
Map<String, Values> map = map1.entrySet().stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                 e -> new Values(BigDecimal.valueOf(e.getValue()),
                         BigDecimal.valueOf(map2.get(e.getKey())))));

 map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
A=123.1, 543.5
B=345.2, 432.2
C=678.3, 654.3
```